# split, filter and join

Tags: javascript, filter, split

I have found this code to solve my problem on Stackoverflow but I am having a hard time understanding what is filter's callback function doing

```
".split(' ').filter(e => e.trim().length).join('-')
```

Comment: filtering it is superfluous, if the spliiting contains one or more whitespaces as regex.

Comment: just to remove whitespaces if the string has spaces at the beginning, end or double spaces. trim() will remove all the extra spaces

Comment: Since you are splitting by space, the resulting array will never have whitespace strings. So, the filter doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say suppose if you are having an array with five elements,

```
let array = [10,20,30,40,50];
```

Filter will just iterate into all the individual elements and returns the desired output,
Like if you need output whatever greater than 30 alone,

```
let result = array.filter(element => element >= 30);
```

and the result will be

```
30,40,50
```

It was introduced in ES6,

Comment: `filter` was not introduced in ES6. And this doesn't answers OP's question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That filter removes whitespace-only substrings:

```js
s = 'aa     bb      cc'

a = s.split(' ').filter(e => e.trim().length).join('-')
b = s.split(' ').join('-')

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

See the difference?